# Es posible editar shared preferences de una aplicacion tercera?

Tags: android, android-studio, app, sharedpreferences

Usualmente puedo acceder a las preferencias de una aplicación mediante un emulador android con root, sin embargo en telefonos sin root me gustaría diseñar una app que me permita sobreescribir preferencias de otra app que no e

Comment: Actualmente no es posible por cuestiones de seguridad.

Answer (score 1):

Hace tiempo se tenía la bandera [WORLD_READABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) hasta que fue obsoleta en la API 17.

> [WORLD_READABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) Permite que todas las demás aplicaciones tengan
>   acceso de lectura al archivo creado, en este caso el archivo de
>   preferencias.

En este caso podías tener un archivo de preferencias que podría ser leído por otras aplicaciones.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);     
String correo = prefs.getString("email", "usuario@dominio.com");
```

**Actualmente por cuestiones de seguridad editar las preferencias de otra aplicación no es posible.**

> Creación de archivos legibles para otras aplicaciones  es muy peligroso y puede causar
>   agujeros de seguridad en aplicaciones. Se desaconseja encarecidamente;
>   En su lugar, las aplicaciones deben utilizar más mecanismo formal para
>   las interacciones tales como `ContentProvider`, `BroadcastReceiver` y
>   servicio. No hay garantías de que este modo de acceso se mantendrá en
>   un archivo, por ejemplo, cuando se pasa por una copia de seguridad y
>   restauración. Presentar el modo de creación, permiten que todas las
>   demás aplicaciones que tienen acceso de lectura al archivo creado.